# how to change the content of my ifame using next and previos button

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```js
function openFiles(fileSlNo){
 var data = { 
 pageMode: "PDF_DISPLAY", 
 fileSlno: fileSlNo 
 };
 var d = $.param(data);
 var request = $
 .ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url:"folderNavigation.do?"+d,
        dataType : "TEXT",
        success: function(responseData){
         //response Data is a URL that returns a strem
         var document=encodeURIComponent(responseData);
         //document is a variable that encodes the URL coming.
            $("#showDialog").html('<iframe src="web/viewer.html?file='+document+'" width="900px" height="650px"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
             
                   create: function(event, ui) {
                $("body").css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
               },
               closeOnEscape: function(event, ui) {
                $("body").css({ overflow: 'inherit' });
               },
                height:'auto',
                width:'auto',
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable:false,
                position:["center",30],
                closeOnEscape: true,
               
                
            });
            
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status + "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
 
    });
 
}
```

```html
<div id="showDialog" title="Document Viewer"style="display: none;"></div>
```

This is how i am doing showing pdf files in a pdf.js viewer as a dialog in iframe using jquery my requirement is to show a list a pdf files using next and previous buttons how to do that please any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the url, use jquery to change the `src` of an existing `iframe`:

```
$('#targetiframe').attr('src', url);
```

P.S.: I recommend you not to declare a variable named `document`.

Comment: thank u for your reply but my response data is dynamic

Comment: you can do it as well in that case

Comment: the pdf document shall not be reloaded if you update only url hash value